# Open close principle and Collective ownership. Extreme Programming

Tags: solid-principles, open-closed-principle, extreme-programming

Reading the Kent Beck's Extreme Programming book I stumbled upon the idea of Collective Ownership which is "Anyone can change any code anywhere in the system at any time."

I see that Collective Ownership contradicts the OCP. But maybe I am mistaken. Or if I am not, maybe someone can compare these two principles form their experience?

Comment: Quoting from the XP tag you used: `QUESTIONS ABOUT SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT METHODS AND PRACTICES OR PROJECT MANAGEMENT ARE OFF-TOPIC. Please consider Software Engineering or Project Management Stack Exchanges for these questions.`. Voting to close.

Comment: Just because you _can_, doesn't mean you _should_.